# Need to Sum if both cells on the same row are greater than Zero

Tags: worksheet-function

I am attempting to create a report that will count the number of total sum of two columns (B4 and C4) only when the both cells on that row are greater than zero.  I would also like to add text "Multichannel" when one or both cells have a zero in it.

This is the formula I created, but it is not working correctly:

```
=IF(B4>0+C4>0,B4+C4,"One Channel")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When doing math, Excel treats `TRUE` as 1 and `FALSE` as 0. If either B4 or C4 are greater than 0, then the result of your conditional will be greater than 0. The way it's written, you have and OR condition, not an AND condition. Technically, what is written won't evaluate correctly for other reasons: You have to separate comparisons with parantheses. What you have evaluates like this:

```
=IF(B3>0+C3>0,B3+C3,"One Channel")
=IF(0>0+11>0,B3+C3,"One Channel")
=IF(0>11>0,B3+C3,"One Channel")
=IF(FALSE>0,B3+C3,"One Channel")
=IF(TRUE,B3+C3,"One Channel")
```

See how it deals with `0+C3` first? I think what you meant was this:

```
=IF((B4>0)+(C4>0),B4+C4,"One Channel")
```

However, that's still not quite right. In the third row in your screenshot, that would evaluate like this:

```
=IF((B3>0)+(C3>0),B3+C3,"One Channel")
=IF((0>0)+(11>0),B3+C3,"One Channel")
=IF(FALSE+TRUE,B3+C3,"One Channel")
=IF(0+1,B3+C3,"One Channel")
=IF(1,B3+C3,"One Channel")
```

You have a few options. One easy change is this:

```
=IF((B4>0)*(C4>0),B4+C4,"One Channel")
```

Multiplying instead of adding makes it an AND condition instead of an OR condition. There are several alternatives, though, based on your needs and comfort level.

```
=IF(AND(B4>0,C4>0),B4+C4,"One Channel")
=IF(B4*C4>0,B4+C4,"One Channel")
=IF(PRODUCT(B4:C4)>0,SUM(B4:C4),"One Channel")
=IF(COUNTIF(B4:C4,0)=0,SUM(B4:C4),"One Channel")
```

That last two are good to check for zeroes across a large range but they're probably overkill for just 2 cells.

Comment: Engineer Toast - You have provided masterful formulas.  I am grateful for your response.  The very last formula was something I attempted to write out earlier, but failed an important component and an added parentheses.   
I am using this one: =IF((B4>0)+(C4>0),B4+C4,"One Channel")  But glad I have this page for future reference!  Thank you kindly!